# Recycle View show difference in android Lollipop

Tags: android

I create a recycleview but it show not clean in android Lollipop.
But in lolipop it not show line between two cardview.
Here is my layout

```
 <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/rvproduct"
    android:layout_weight="9"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp">
</android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>
```

and Cardview layout:

```
    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        android:id="@+id/cvsp"
        card_view:cardUseCompatPadding="true"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="90dp">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="@color/white"
            android:padding="8dp"
            android:weightSum="7"
            >

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/product_photo"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:background="@null"
                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:src="@drawable/logodms" />

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/liner"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/product_photo"
                android:background="@color/white"
                android:layout_weight="4"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:weightSum="4"
                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
              >

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/product_name"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:background="@color/white"
                    android:layout_height="0dp"
                    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:text="Vitamin Messi"
                    android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"

                    android:textColorHighlight="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />
                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/product_unitprice"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:background="@color/white"
                    android:layout_height="0dp"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/product_name"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:text="4.000/LE 10.000/CHAN"
                    android:textColor="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
                    android:textColorHighlight="@color/colorPrimary"
                    android:textStyle="italic" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/product_saleunitofmeasure"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="0dp"
                    android:background="@color/white"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/product_name"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:text="Hộp"
                    android:textStyle="italic" />
                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/product_No"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:background="@color/white"
                    android:layout_height="0dp"
                    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:textSize="10dp"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />

            </LinearLayout>
            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="2"
                android:background="@color/white"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:weightSum="3"
                android:layout_height="match_parent">
                <TextView
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:background="@color/white"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="0dp"
                    android:text="Số lượng"
                    android:textStyle="bold"
                    android:textSize="10dp"
                    android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"
                    android:id="@+id/textView7"
                    android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/product_tonkho"
                    android:background="@color/white"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="0dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"

                    android:textSize="15dp"
                    android:textColor="@color/black"
                    android:textStyle="bold"
                    android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
                    />
                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/product_chietkhau"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="0dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:background="@color/white"
                    android:textSize="10dp"
                    android:textColor="@color/green"
                    android:textStyle="bold"
                    android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
                    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" />
            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

Look here in android 4.4 and android 5.0

Android 4.4:
 [image: Look so cool]
Android 5.0:
[image: So bad]

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem today.

I simply added a margin to my LinearLayout wrapper. Your parent cell is a CardView so try adding a margin to it. You won't get the same "card" look but it does look like cells and it's attractive.

However I recommend that you always have a Linear/RelativeLayout as your base cell. The reason for this is because having a Linear/RelativeLayout wrapper makes aligning the children much easier.

```
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
    android:id="@+id/cvsp"
    card_view:cardUseCompatPadding="true"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="90dp"
    android:layout_margin="5dp">
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to add attr **cardElevation** to CardView. Eg:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
card_view:cardCornerRadius="0dp"
card_view:cardElevation="1dp">
```

You may prefer to add spacing between items using **ItemDecoration**. Eg:

```
public class SpaceItemDecoration extends RecyclerView.ItemDecoration {
private int space;

public SpaceItemDecoration(int space) {
    this.space = space;
}

@Override
public void getItemOffsets(Rect outRect, View view, RecyclerView parent, RecyclerView.State state) {
    outRect.left = space;
    outRect.right = space;
    outRect.bottom = space;

    if(parent.getChildPosition(view) == 0)
        outRect.top = space;
}
```

and:

```
yourRecycleView.addItemDecoration(new SpaceItemDecoration(3));
```

**P/s:** I know "TÔI ĐÃ THẤY HOA VÀNG TRÊN CỎ XANH" ;-)

Comment: i try this, but nothing change :(. you know "TÔI ĐÃ THẤY HOA VÀNG TRÊN CỎ XANH" . oh great. you come from?

Comment: I'm from the place on which makes this film. Unfortunately, no chat-chit :(. Happy coding!